# A3 Indesign file export to A4 PDF

Tags: pdf, export, adobe-indesign

I have an A3 indesign file which is my portfolio and I'm needing to export a pdf which is suitable for an Job upload (max 8mb) but because its a3 its just too large, is there any way to export to an A4 pdf ? I really cant find any answers online.

Also how to reduce to size of a PDF without reducing its quality ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This site is about programming, hence your question is off-topic

Comment: That said, the size of your PDF (file size) is not related to the size of the page. Instead, if the file size of your file is too big, you need to have a look at the PDF settings in InDesign you are using to export your file to PDF. More than likely changing the PDF settings to downsample or compress images differently will reduce the size of your PDF. That will bring some quality loss with it, but this is unavoidable.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche: only true if it actually contains raster images. Pure vector images cannot be lossy compressed.

Comment: Good point and very correct!

Answer (score 1):

As PDF is a vector based format, you can resize A3 to A4 without losing the fidelity. However, it will not reduce the size as well.

Comment: Don't forget that PDF isn't "just" a raster format. It can, and most PDFs have, images in it that can be resized down without loosing fidelity. But if you did that you wouldn't save any file size.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche well what is the answer? to exporting to a4 when my file is a3....?

Comment: Did you read my comment on your original question? I answered exactly what you could do.